# File.Exists fails on Azure Website

Tags: c#, azure, web

I am deploying my website to an Azure website. I need to work with a special file type in code behind and this work on my development machine but when I deploy to Azure it can't find the file?

```
var real_File = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/FolderName/Filename.w00");
if (File.Exists(real_file))
{
     lblStatus.Text = "File exists.";
}
else
{
     lblStatus.Text = "File could not be found.";
}
```

Is there something I must configure in Azure to get this to work?

Comment: Have you checked what the value is of `real_File` when deployed on Azure?

Comment: Did you check using FTP that your file really exist in following location?

Comment: Thanks guys. Your answers helped me solve the problem. I logged on to the site through FTP and realised that the folder was missing.

Comment: I believe that you should store your file using Local Storage. Take a look too.

Answer (score 1):

Is the file in your VS solution?  If so, have you set the "Copy Always" attribute on the file?

This could be a problem with your current directory (Environment.CurrentDirectory) being different on your development environment.  I would build a full path to the file based on where you actually think it is, not just the relative path to the current directory.  If you know it's in the same directory as your deployed assemblies, you can use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.

Also, logging may help you here.